# Upper bound on largest eigenvalue of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a square matrix with all eigenvalues in the unit disk: $|\lambda(A)| \leq 1$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda(A)$.

I am wondering if all the eigenvalues of $A + A^T$ are in twice the unit disk:
$\lambda(A + A^T) \leq 2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Take the two by two identity matrix and add a 2 above the diagonal.